# Error importing n3-charts module into ES6 application

Tags: angularjs, npm, es6-modules, n3-charts

I am having a problem incorporating n3-charts into my ES6 code. Following these steps I used npm to install n3-charts:

```
npm install n3-charts
```

And then import it into the code:

```
import n3charts from 'n3-charts';
```

However this is the error when the code is built:

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module 'n3-charts' from 'C:\myapp']
stream:
Labeled {
 _readableState:
  ReadableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 16,
    buffer: [Object],
    length: 0,
    pipes: [Object],
    pipesCount: 1,
    flowing: true,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: true,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    ranOut: false,
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null },
 readable: true,
 domain: null,
 _events:
  { end: [Object],
    error: [Object],
    data: [Function: ondata],
    _mutate: [Object] },
 _eventsCount: 4,
 _maxListeners: undefined,
 _writableState:
  WritableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 16,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: true,
    ended: true,
    finished: true,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    bufferedRequest: null,
    lastBufferedRequest: null,
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: true,
    errorEmitted: false,
    bufferedRequestCount: 0,
    corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
 writable: false,
 allowHalfOpen: true,
 _options: { objectMode: true },
 _wrapOptions: { objectMode: true },
 _streams: [ [Object] ],
 length: 1,
 label: 'deps' } }
```

What could be the problem? Or, how do I troubleshoot this?